# Sprite disappears after adding a material to it

Tags: unity, sprites, materials

I have background which is FirsLayer, order in layer 0 and platform over it which is FirstLayer, order in layer 1.

[image]

Once I add a material to the platform, the layer doesn't seem to change but it gets rendered behind the background.

The material that I add:

[image]

1)Why do I get such results?

2) How can I add the material to the platform and still keep it above the background?

P.S. For further clarification if somebody didn't understand, I expected the sprite to stay on its original position(i.e. not to go behind the background when a material is being added to it)

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Tell us what you're expecting, more details on what's happening and what you've tried to do to fix it already.

Comment: @Byte56 I know you're simply doing your work as a moderator and trying to help this community or whatever :D but I think that here the context of the questions says it quite clearly. I expect the sprite to keep its initial position(i.e. not to move behind or in front of some others) when a material is being added to it but for the sake of clarification I will write it down. 

Okay, fixed, and thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1) Because if you want to use the sorting layers in unity, you can't use many of the materials that are available but only a few.

2) You're limited to only a few materials, which work in harmony with unity's sorting layers.

Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the questions you yourself asked. It's just a description of the results. It doesn't answer "Why" or your second question.

Comment: Okay @Byte56 everything is fixed! Hope it's better structured now. At first I answered in 1 simple sentece, because IMO it was pretty much the same as to separate it into two different. If you still think it doesn't fit, you can simply write the "good" answer yourself and I'm going to accept it, and done! Cheers!